# increase background-space for “product label images”

Tags: magento

please visit this link : http://schoolboards4.newtrendzonline.com/index.php/snowman-markers/whiteboard-markers/snowman-whiteboard-markers-round-tip.html here on products ,you can see label-image : "ultimate" but Background-space for "ultimate" is very less.

please guide me to "how to increase the size of the mango shaped "background-space".

let me know if you need any clarifications.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This icon is contained in this sprite: http://schoolboards4.newtrendzonline.com/skin/frontend/default/galarainbow/images/productlabel_icons.png To change the size of it you will need to edit this png file and resize the icon (in Photoshop or Gimp etc)

Comment: please help me here : http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/34655/difficult-to-select-sub-categories-in-magento?noredirect=1#comment47271_34655